# ${__RandomString(10,195165984,)} is not working when placed in a script file outside Jmeter and then calling it

Tags: javascript, java, groovy, jmeter

I want to have a script file separately, outside JMeter which has some JS functions, such as `${__RandomString(10,195165984,)}`.

While I save the file in .groovy format and then call it in the Script file (FileName), I am getting an error as follows:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.$() is applicable for argument types: (Script7$_run_closure1) values: [Script7$_run_closure1@1aa89172]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), get(java.lang.String), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:194) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.assertions.JSR223Assertion.getResult(JSR223Assertion.java:49) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processAssertion(JMeterThread.java:901) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.checkAssertions(JMeterThread.java:892) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:565) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.$() is applicable for argument types: (Script7$_run_closure1) values: [Script7$_run_closure1@1aa89172]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), get(java.lang.String), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.callGlobal(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:403) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.access$100(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:94) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl$3.invokeMethod(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:307) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at Script7.run(Script7.groovy:2) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    ... 10 more
```

This works fine when I write these functions inside JMeter script. Is there something I am missing? or we cannot call those functions outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in Groovy scripts, either use `Parameters` section like:

1. Create `test.groovy` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation with the following contents:

   ```
   log.info("Random number: " + Parameters)
   ```
2. Pass the function into "Parameters" section:

   [image]

---

Alternatively you can call [RandomUtils.nextInt()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html#nextInt-int-int-) function directly in your groovy file like:

```
log.info("Random number: " + org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(10, 195165984))
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 1):

When you call it inside jmeter, the function is interpreted and replaced by the value.

It’s not when in a groovy external file.

But in both case don’t do that, use Parameters field to call it and then use Parameters value directly.

Comment: So this is not possible. The way you explained, can you give an example?